# How to get table cell text based on target row with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the text of a table cell based on the cell index and a row identifier. In the sample table below, I'd like to get the text of the cell in the same row as the cell "text6". Here's a sample of the table I'm dealing with:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fixedTable" id="PackageTable_dataTable" style="width: 1262px;">
<tbody class="tableData" id="PackageTable_dataBody">
<tr height="24px" uid="section1" index="0" class="alternateRow">
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 193px;"><span title="text1">text1</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 57px;"><span title="text2">text2</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 115px;"><span title="text3">text3</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr height="24px" uid="section2" index="1" class="alternateRow">
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 193px;"><span title="text4">text4</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 57px;"><span title="text5">text5</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 115px;"><span title="text6">text6</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr height="24px" uid="section3" index="2" class="alternateRow">
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 193px;"><span title="text7">text7</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 57px;"><span title="text8">text8</span></div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 115px;"><span title="text9">text9</span></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here's my non-working code:

```
public static string returnTableCellValue(string TableID, string TableRowIdentifier, int targetCellIndex)
        {
            string cellValue = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                IWebElement baseTable = Global.driver.FindElement(By.Id(TableID));
                // gets all table rows
                ICollection<IWebElement> rows = baseTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
                // for every row
                foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
                {
                    if (row.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='" + TableRowIdentifier + "']")).Displayed)
                    {
                        Global.log.WriteLine("row identifier found!");
                        IWebElement key = row.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[" + targetCellIndex + "]"));
                        IWebElement keySpan = key.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));
                        cellValue = keySpan.Text;
                    }
                }
                return cellValue;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Global.log.WriteLine("returnTableCellValue exception: " + ex.ToString());
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: How does it not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Arran, thanks for your reply. As Faiz pointed out below, my code with give an ElementNotFound exception when it encounters the first row without the identifier. His suggested code doesn't seem to work - no exceptions but no row found. My code wasn't finding the correct unique row with the identifier. Any other suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line in your code will throw `NoSuchElementException` on the first row that  `FindElement` doesnot not find an element with the matching criteria.

```
if (row.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='" + tableRowIdentifier + "']")).Displayed)
```

Use FindElements() instead, as follows:

```
IWebElement matchedRow = null;
try
{
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        if(row.FindElements(By.XPath("td/span")).FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.Text.Trim().Equals(TableRowIdentifier)) != null)
        {
            matchedRow = row;
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
    //couldnot find 
    matchedRow = null;
}

if(matchedRow !=null)
{
    cellValue = matchedRow.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("td[{0}]/span",targetCellIndex)).Text;
}

return cellValue;
```

Comment: The line: row.FindElements(By.XPath("td/span")).FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.Text.Trim().Equals(TableRowIdentifier)) != null doesn't find the correct row and so no data is returned. Any idea why that line isn't returned the correct row?

Comment: Sorry, the above code does work - I was using the wrong xpath expression when I tested it locally. Thanks very much Faiz and Arran